# Problem with addition of neighboring pixels

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement de-noising using non local means algorithm. I am having an issue in regards to addition of pixels.

```
// Find the patch differences by blurring the difference images
            d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[0].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[0].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[1].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[1].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[2].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[2].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[3].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[3].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[4].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[4].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[5].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[5].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[6].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[6].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[7].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[7].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[8].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[8].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
```

When I tried to print the output using the following code,

```
if (i == 154 && j == 35) {
                cout << endl << "At 154 and 35";
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) << " = " << d_channels[0].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) << " + " << d_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) << " + " << d_channels[0].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[2].at<float>(i, j);
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[5].at<float>(i, j);
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[8].at<float>(i, j);

            }
```

it gave me this,

[image]

As you can see, the addition is not properly updated.

However, When I modify the line

```
d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[0].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[0].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
```

to

```
d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[0].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[0].at<float>(i, j);// +d_channels[0].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
```

It is giving me an apt output.

[image]

I don't understand where it is going wrong. I checked the entire code and declarations multiple times, but i am not able to figure out why its going wrong with `d_channels[0].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j)`.

I would really be thankful if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

I have attached the entire code(with declarations) below for better understanding

```
// image_read.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "math.h"
#include <chrono>    

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img_rev = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/denoise_input_h.png");
    //Mat ideal = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/den_check_2.png");
    int search_area = 3;
    int patch_size = 3;//dx
    float sigma = 0.12;//dy
    cout << img_rev.rows << "," << img_rev.cols << endl;
    cvtColor(img_rev, img_rev, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    img_rev.convertTo(img_rev, CV_32F);
    img_rev = img_rev / 256.0;
    array<Mat, 3> channels;
    split(img_rev, channels);
    Mat red = channels[0].clone();
    Mat green = channels[1].clone();
    Mat blue = channels[2].clone();

    //define nine channels, one for each in the 3x3 search window
    Mat dc_red_four(img_rev.rows, img_rev.cols, CV_32FC(9));
    Mat dc_green_four(img_rev.rows, img_rev.cols, CV_32FC(9));
    Mat dc_blue_four(img_rev.rows, img_rev.cols, CV_32FC(9));
    cout << dc_blue_four.channels();

    array<Mat, 9> red_channels;
    split(dc_red_four, red_channels);

    array<Mat, 9> green_channels;
    split(dc_green_four, green_channels);

    array<Mat, 9> blue_channels;
    split(dc_blue_four, blue_channels);

    Mat d(img_rev.rows, img_rev.cols, CV_32FC(9));
    array<Mat, 9> d_channels;
    split(d, d_channels);

    Mat blur_d_y(img_rev.rows, img_rev.cols, CV_32FC(9));
    array<Mat, 9> d_y_channels;
    split(blur_d_y, d_y_channels);
    /*
    0 = -1,-1
    1 = -1, 0
    2 = -1, 1
    3 =  0,-1
    4 =  0, 0
    5 =  0, 1
    6 =  1,-1
    7 =  1, 0
    8 =  1, 1
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < img_rev.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img_rev.cols; j++)
        {
            //creating the 3x3 window and squaring the distance
            red_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), max(j - 1, 0))) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), max(j - 1, 0)));
            red_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j)) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j));
            red_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            red_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(i, max(j - 1, 0))) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(i, max(j - 1, 0)));
            red_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(i, j)) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(i, j));
            red_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(i, min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(i, min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            red_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), max(j - 1, 0))) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), max(j - 1, 0)));
            red_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j)) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j));
            red_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) = (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (red.at<float>(i, j) - red.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            //green
            green_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), max(j - 1, 0))) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), max(j - 1, 0)));
            green_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j)) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j));
            green_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            green_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(i, max(j - 1, 0))) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(i, max(j - 1, 0)));
            green_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(i, j)) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(i, j));
            green_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(i, min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(i, min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            green_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), max(j - 1, 0))) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), max(j - 1, 0)));
            green_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j)) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j));
            green_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) = (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (green.at<float>(i, j) - green.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            //blue
            blue_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), max(j - 1, 0))) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), max(j - 1, 0)));
            blue_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j)) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j));
            blue_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            blue_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(i, max(j - 1, 0))) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(i, max(j - 1, 0)));
            blue_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(i, j)) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(i, j));
            blue_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(i, min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(i, min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            blue_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), max(j - 1, 0))) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), max(j - 1, 0)));
            blue_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j)) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j));
            blue_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) = (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1))) * (blue.at<float>(i, j) - blue.at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), min(j + 1, img_rev.cols - 1)));

            //sum across colour channels
            d_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[0].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[1].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[2].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[3].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[4].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[5].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[6].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[7].at<float>(i, j);
            d_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) = red_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) + green_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) + blue_channels[8].at<float>(i, j);

            // Find the patch differences by blurring the difference images
            d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[0].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[0].at<float>(i, j);// +d_channels[0].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[1].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[1].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[2].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[2].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[2].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[3].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[3].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[4].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[4].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[5].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[5].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[5].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[6].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[6].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[7].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[7].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);
            d_y_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) = d_channels[8].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) + d_channels[8].at<float>(i, j) + d_channels[8].at<float>(min(i + 1, img_rev.rows - 1), j);

            

            if (i == 154 && j == 35) {
                cout << endl << "At 154 and 35";
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) << " = " << d_channels[0].at<float>(max(i - 1, 0), j) << " + " << d_channels[0].at<float>(i, j);
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[0].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[1].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[2].at<float>(i, j);
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[3].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[4].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[5].at<float>(i, j);
                cout << endl << d_y_channels[6].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[7].at<float>(i, j) << "," << d_y_channels[8].at<float>(i, j);

            }


        }
    }




    //cvtColor(img_rev, img_rev, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    //cout << img_rev;

    //cout << ideal;
    cout << endl << "finished";
    waitKey(100000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are saying some of the matrix give wired number?  try to print the input to the entry of the strange number>? like what you did for the first one

Comment: well, even though if its a weird number(lets call it 'a'). That is not the problem, the problem is when 'a' is added to two other values, the addition is not being computed properly and the final result is being 'a'.

Comment: std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << f << '\n';  try this. see whether it remove the funny thing behind

Comment: I realized what my mistake was, I should be blurring in a different loop that garbage value (a) was close to 400 million and hence 400 million was the final value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what `-4.316e+08` means? It is 400 million. Adding 400 million + 0.04 is 400 million. This addition is totally correct.

The problem is that you are computing `d_channels` sequentially, and within the same loop you want to compute `d_y_channels` that needs a value of `d_channels` that you haven't computed yet. Thus, you read an uninitialized value, which in this case is `-4.316e+08`, but could be anything.

You should do the blurring in a separate loop. This way, you first compute all of `d_channels`, and when you do the blurring, all the values you need are already computed.

Comment: How did i miss this, Thats totally correct. Thanks a lot